# Reading dataframe from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
d={0:[('cat_a', 15),('cat_b', 12)], 
1: [('cat_a',10),('cat_b',7)],
2:[('cat_a', 12),('cat_b', 8)]}
```

I get a dataframe by using below:

```
data = [l for l in d.values()]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['cat_a','cat_b'])
```

In each column i get tuples, out of which i only need the numerical value.

Comment: What is the expected result? I see that in row 1 you have `cat_b` and `cat_a` reversed...

Comment: I didnt notice that. For now I edit and simplify the problem with cat_a and cat_b in same order in each indexes in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, d.values()))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   cat_a  cat_b
0     15     12
1     10      7
2     12      8
```

Comment: `dict(zip(d, map(dict, d.values())))` if you want to keep the indices ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {k2:v2 for k2,v2 in l} for k,l in d.items()}, orient='index')

# or for a functional approach like that of @Andrej
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(d, map(dict, d.values()))), orient='index')
```

output:

```
   cat_a  cat_b
0     15     12
1      7     10
2     12      8
```

used input:

```
d = {0: [('cat_a', 15),('cat_b', 12)], 
     1: [('cat_b',10),('cat_a',7)],
     2: [('cat_a', 12),('cat_b', 8)]}
```